# asm("trap") on 64-bit iOS devices

Tags: ios, arm64

In my homegrown assert macro, I've been using asm("trap") on iOS devices (or asm("int3") on iOS simulators) to break in the debugger.  However, in 64-bit builds for devices, I get an "unrecognized instruction mnemonic" for the trap instruction.  Is there an equivalent for arm64?

(Alternatives like __builtin_trap() or raise(SIGINT) do work, but have some behavior I don't like; the former won't let you continue past the break, and the latter is a function so you're always one step below where you need to be in the stack when you break.)

Answer (score 8):

I was able to break into the debugger (and continue afterwards) with `asm("svc 0");`. I’m not sure this is the *correct* way but it seems to do the job.

Comment: It's not correct. It calls unknown syscall and this raises [SIGSYS signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGSYS) (Bad system call) and debugger catches it. I think it's better to [send SIGSTOP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44142833/468725) instead

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried iOS, but on Linux, the `brk` instruction causes `SIGTRAP` to be raised, which traps to the debugger if one is running.

```
asm("brk #0");
```

Comment: This would be architecture-specific, right?  So unless you're running Linux on arm64, I don't think it would apply to iOS.

Comment: Well, the instruction generates a Breakpoint Instruction exception - that part is defined by the arm64 architecture and is OS-independent.  Linux handles the exception by raising SIGTRAP.  I am guessing that iOS would handle it by invoking whatever debugger facility might be available.  I don't know the details of that, but it's what I would suggest trying.  Of course, feedback from someone who tries it would be useful; if it actually doesn't work I'll delete the answer.